# How do I get logcat into ACRA reports for background crashes?

Tags: android, crash-reports, android-logcat, acra

I've setup ACRA to include logcat via the READ_LOGS permission.  It works great when the app crashes in the foreground, but not when it's in the background.  Then the logs are just a dump of memory and cpu usage.  I think my app may have been killed by Android to free up memory, which I'm guessing prevents ACRA's default behaviors.  Is there any way around this?

Comment: Why use ACRA when Crashlytics is free?

Answer (score 0):

If you app is still running (in the background) then ACRA should be able to grab the logs.

But honestly if your app has crashed you should be able to figure it out just from the stacktrace.

Comment: My guess is my app is being terminated by Android to free up memory.  I don't really know though because it doesn't happen until a while after I background my app and do other things.  The info it includes in that email doesn't have anything about a crash or exception.

Comment: So you are getting an ACRA report from your app that doesn't contain a stacktrace?

Comment: I assume it's from ACRA as I wasn't getting them before I implemented logging.  It's radically different from regular ACRA logs though since it doesn't include a stacktrace, but includes a screenshot and a pretty useless system log.

Comment: ACRA doesn't take screenshots. Is this report being sent to your ACRA backend? If so, what else besides ACRA have been confgugred with that end point?

Comment: Hrm, so it's possibly some system logging?  I just have ACRA setup to send emails, no backend involved.

Comment: Its sounds like what happens when you capture a bug report via the Android frameowkr.